# Passing data in laravel view mail

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

im trying to pass more than one variable in my controller to go to the view, but is giving me the error of undifined variable.

I been looking to the documentation and other posts, and still not working.

Controller:

```
 Mail::send('emails.send-references', ['user' => $user,'price'=>$ref->value], function ($m) use ($user) {
            $m->from('no-reply@myemal', 'Myname');

            $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('My Suject RefMe!');
        });


Views mail:
Hello{{$user->name}}blabla:<br>
Ref:{{$refnumber}} <br>
Value: {{$price}}€
```

Comment: You're only passing `$user` and `$price` to the view, but in the email view you're also using a `$refnumber` variable. You need to pass that as well, otherwise it will throw and undefined variable exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending the $refnumber value to the view:

You can send it like this:

```
$data = [
    'user' => $user,
    'price'=>$ref->value,
    'refnumber' => 'foo' 
];


Mail::send('emails.send-references', $data, function ($m) use ($user) {
            $m->from('no-reply@myemal', 'Myname');

            $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('My Suject RefMe!');
        });
```

Views mail:

```
Hello{{$user->name}}blabla:<br>
Ref:{{$refnumber}} <br>
Value: {{$price}}€
```